# JTable color only edited cells

Tags: java, tablecellrenderer

What I have to do is to color editing cell red (TableModelListener is called) and after I press button SEND all red cells become green. How can I achieve this?

```
final JTable Misc_Table = new JTable(model){
         @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
                Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
                Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row, col);

                    /////what to do?///       
                return comp;
            }
    };
```

This is my read button. Selected variable is just a selected ComboBox index number.

```
    Read.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {
            try {
                int register = Integer.parseInt(Register_Text_Field.getText());
                int count = Integer.parseInt(Amount_Text_Field.getText());
                int position = Integer.parseInt(BitPos_Text_Field.getText());

                String[] result = new String[count];

                int selected = (int) Functions_ComboBox.getSelectedIndex();

                    if(selected == 0){
                            result = BackEnd.ReadMultiple_16Bit(251, register, count).get16BitString();
                            //BackEnd.closeSerial();
                    }

                    else if(selected == 1){
                            result = BackEnd.ReadMultiple_32Bit(251, register, count).get32BitString();
                            //BackEnd.closeSerial();
                    }

                    else if(selected == 2){
                            result = BackEnd.ReadMultiple_Float(251, register, count).getFloatString();
                            //BackEnd.closeSerial();
                    }

                    else if(selected == 3){
                            result = BackEnd.ReadCoilStatus(251, register, count).getCoilString();
                            //BackEnd.closeSerial();
                    }

                    else if(selected == 4){
                            result = BackEnd.ReadDiscreteInputStatus(251, register, count).getStringDiscreteInputResult();
                            //BackEnd.closeSerial();
                    }

                    else if(selected == 5){
                            result = BackEnd.ReadAnalogInputRegisters(251, register, count).getStringAnalogInputRegistersResult();
                            //BackEnd.closeSerial();
                    }

                    else if(selected == 6){
                            result = BackEnd.ReadBit(251, register, position, count).getReadBitString();
                            //BackEnd.closeSerial();
                    }

                if (model.getRowCount() > 0)
                {
                    model.setNumRows(0);
                }

                for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++)
                { 
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{register++,
                            result[i]});
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            }
        }
    });
```

This is sending values that have been edited.

```
    Misc_Table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

          public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

             int row = e.getFirstRow();
             int col = e.getColumn();

              Send.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    try {
                        int selected = (int) Functions_ComboBox.getSelectedIndex();

                        String  val = (String) model.getValueAt(row, col);

                        if(selected == 0){
                            int int_Val = Integer.parseInt(val);
                            BackEnd.WriteMultiple_16Bit(unitID, row, int_Val , 1);
                        }

                        else if(selected == 1){
                            int int_Val = Integer.parseInt(val);
                            BackEnd.WriteMultiple_32Bit(unitID, row, int_Val , 1);
                        }

                        else if(selected == 2){
                            float float_Val = Float.parseFloat(val);
                            BackEnd.WriteMultiple_Float(unitID, row, float_Val, 1); 
                        }

                        else if(selected == 6){
                            int position = Integer.parseInt(BitPos_Text_Field.getText());
                            BackEnd.WriteBit(unitID, row, position, true, 1);
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ea) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MISC,"Wrong number format.");
                    }
                }

              });    
          }
        });
```

Comment: Perhaps, if you create a **runnable** project that we can copy into our IDE, we can help.  In general, create a GUI model that has an isDirty flag for each value.  When true, set the cell to red.  When the send button is pressed, write all the dirty values to  the database and reset the isDirty flags to false.